# Renaming a class Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to rename a class in VS 2017 (C#) but the popup that asks me to rename all the references doesn't show up. Best answer to find was [rename class with file name in one step in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244144/rename-class-with-file-name-in-one-step-in-visual-studio) but it doesn't asnwer my question. May I have turned it off or something?

Comment: Try restarting your visual studio.

Comment: @BobSwager didn't work

Comment: Find your instances and change it manually. :D

Comment: @BobSwager yea but imagine if I use it in 1000 classes ... :D anyway idk why when I renamed an other class the pop-up showed up

Comment: Can you provide your code for that class ?

Comment: @BobSwager not rly ... it's way too big and I don't think the code is the problem

Comment: I am having the same problem with several very small files in a small project. @Takeshi's suggestion is already selected.

Comment: That's it, going back to vi......

Answer (score 2):

There is an option that enables symbolic renaming.

Try this.

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General. 
Search for the option "Prompt for symbolic renaming when renaming files"

That should fire up the dialog when renaming files.